# which of these methods to mirror a tree is better in terms of time and space-complexity

Tags: java, optimization, tree, time-complexity, space-complexity

Here are two methods I have written below to mirror a tree in Java both of which work correctly.  I have just learned time-complexity and I wanted to know which method worked better in terms of their time-complexities and their space-complexities.  The first method I made myself and the second method was given to me by my teacher.  The main reason difference between the two methods is that in the first method, no new tree is created whereas one is made in the second method.  Thanks in advance!

```
//way 1
public static TreeNode mirrorImage (TreeNode t) {

    if (t == null)
        return null;

    TreeNode right = t.getRight();
    TreeNode left = t.getLeft();

    t.setLeft(mirrorImage(right));
    t.setRight(mirrorImage(left));

    return t;

}

//way 2
public static TreeNode mirrorImage (TreeNode t) {

    if (t == null)
        return null;
    else
        return new TreeNode (t.getValue(), mirrorImage(t.getRight()), 
           mirrorImage(t.getLeft()));
}
```

Here is the treeNode class for your help also :)

```
class TreeNode {

    private Object value; 
    private TreeNode left, right;

    public TreeNode(Object initValue) { 
        value = initValue; 
        left = null; 
        right = null; 
    }

    public TreeNode(Object initValue, TreeNode initLeft, TreeNode initRight) { 
        value = initValue; 
        left = initLeft; 
        right = initRight; 
    }

    public Object getValue() { 
        return value; 
    }

    public TreeNode getLeft()  { 
        return left; 
    }

    public TreeNode getRight()  { 
        return right; 
    }

    public void setValue(Object theNewValue)  { 
        value = theNewValue; 
    }

    public void setLeft(TreeNode theNewLeft)  { 
        left = theNewLeft;
    }

    public void setRight(TreeNode theNewRight) { 
        right = theNewRight;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no difference in time complexity. 
Where `n` is the number of TreeNodes, the time complexity is `O(n)` in both cases. You're visiting every TreeNode once.

Way 1 has space complexity `O(1)` and way 2 has space complexity `O(n)`, given that the original tree already exists. If you count the construction of the original tree as part of the algorithm, the space complexity is `O(n)` in both cases, as `O(2n)` == `O(n)`.